Como crear archivos desde controlador java en imagen docker y que persistan?
Estoy desplegando mi aplicacion spring boot en docker y tengo un problema al momento de crear un archivo desde un controlador java, he creado las carpetas: /app/images/activaciones, /app/images/pagoMensual, /app/images/pagos, /app/images/productos, pero las está guardando en la ruta: src/main/resources/static/images/.../
Lo que necesito es poder guardar los archivos que cargo desde el controlador en una ruta que persiste y que pueda acceder a ella desde una vista html
A continuación comparto el controlador, configuracion Dockferfile y docker-compose.yml
controlador:
    if(!imagen.isEmpty())

    {
        String nombreImagen = "producto_" + producto.getId() + ".png";
        producto.setImagen(nombreImagen);
        try {
            byte[] bytes = imagen.getBytes();
            Path ruta = Path ruta = Paths.get("/app/images/productos/" + nombreImagen);

            if (Files.exists(ruta)) {
                Files.delete(ruta);
            }
            Files.write(ruta, bytes);
            log.info("Imagen subida correctamente");
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messageOK", "Imagen subida correctamente");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error al subir la imagen", e);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messageKO", "Error al subir la imagen");
        }
        productoService.editProducto(producto);
    }else if(id!=null)
    {
        producto.setImagen(productoService.getProductoById(id).getImagen());
    }


Dockerfile:
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /root
COPY ./pom.xml /root
COPY ./.mvn /root/.mvn
COPY ./mvnw /root
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline
COPY ./src /root/src

RUN mkdir -p /app/images/activaciones /app/images/pagoMensual /app/images/pagos /app/images/productos

RUN ./mvnw clean install -DskipTests

ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "/root/target/aplicacion-0.0.1.jar" ]

docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'
services:
  aplicacion-image:
    image: aplicacion-image
    container_name: aplicacion-container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - aplicacion-network
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - aplicacion-images:/app/images  
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql_container
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - aplicacion-network
    volumes:
      - mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****************
      MYSQL_DATABASE: aplicacion2
      MYSQL_USER: xxxxxxxxxx
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ****************
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
         
networks:
  aplicacion-network:

volumes:
  mysql-volume:
  aplicacion-images:


hola, cual es el error ?

realmente no es un error, es un problema, que no me permite guardar archivos, pero ya lo pude solucionar

Lo solucioné de la siguiente forma:
Creé una clase WebConfig:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:/app/images/");
    }
}

En la configuracion del archivo Dockerfile agregué la configuracion:
# Crear las carpetas necesarias para almacenar las imágenes dentro del contenedor
RUN mkdir -p /app/images/activaciones /app/images/pagoMensual /app/images/pagos /app/images/productos

y en la configuracion del docker-compose agregué un volume:
volumes:
      # Enlazar la carpeta de la máquina anfitriona con la del contenedor
      - /root/images:/app/images

